# push_back from vector in vector causes bad_alloc

Tags: c++, bad-alloc

I'm working on a large project and a line similar to `newVec.push_back(vec[i]);` causes the error `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what():  std::bad_alloc`.

However, I can *not* reproduce the error in a minimized example, but the code looks similar to this:

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyClass {
    public:
    vector<int> vec{1,2,3};
};

class MyClassTwo {
    public:
    vector<int> vec;
};

vector<int> doSometing(const vector<int> vec) {
        vector<int> newVec;
        for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
            newVec.push_back(vec[i]); //causes: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what():  std::bad_alloc
        }
        return newVec;
    }

int main() {
    MyClass c;
    MyClassTwo cTwo;

    cTwo.vec = doSometing(c.vec);

    cout << cTwo.vec[0] << endl;
}
```

Does someone has an idea, what I should check?

Comment: If this example is indicative of how the code in your project is written, then you can start by not passing vectors by value when all you need is to read them. That is bound to increase the memory consumption of your program and make `std::bad_alloc` that much more likely.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb5f149245f414b0)

Comment: If you are trying to copy a vector into another why not `std::copy` ? (Even the vector constructor can take an input range and copy assign)

Comment: How large are your vectors? On what system are you running the program? How much memory does it have? Will the memory become very fragmented?

Comment: in your real code, is it a `std::vector<int>` or some `std::vector<foo>` ?

Comment: And for this, why not just do `newVec = vec;`? That should properly resize `newVec` without a need to resize it for every `push_back`. The copying should be quicker as well.

Comment: @NathanOliver as I said in my Question "However, I can not reproduce the error in a minimized example, but the code looks similar to this:"

Comment: @KostasRim This is not my real code. I'm "sorting" the vector

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude all vectors contain less than 100 elements

Comment: @user463035818 int and double

Comment: Could you copy-paste here the entire error stack? In particular, are you sure the exception occurs at the push_back line, and not anywhere else?

Comment: @InonPeled when I comment the push_back out, the code runs

Comment: @Ben Can you nevertheless copy-paste here the full error stack? Also, look carefully in that line in your actual code, and check if by mistake, you are feeding elements of the vector to the same vector.

Comment: @InonPeled where do I get the "full error stack"? (I'm new to C++ and using Clion)

Comment: @Ben full error stack = all output of your program when it crashes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191026/discussion-between-inon-peled-and-ben).